# BlackBerry WiFi and cell based location API

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, wifi, cell

Does Blackberry API 5.0 support WiFi and cell-tower based geolocation, or is only GPS based geolocation supported? I ask because geolocation is still feasible if we fetch the list of WiFi access points and cell-tower info and submit it to the Google Location Web service.

The question is, must I do this manually or does the BlackBerry geo-location API support these features out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High level overview of GPS Blackberry's JSR 179 implementation.
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/lbs-summary.html

But the jest of it is that it's base on how you construct your Criteria Object: 
Here is a table from [this java doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/Criteria.html) on the class:

RIM Implementation Mode Chart - Generic
Horizontal Accuracy

```
Vertical Accuracy Cost        Power Consumption    Resulting                        Mode
N/A               N/A         Not Allowed          N/A                              Autonomous
N/A               N/A         Allowed              Medium, High or No Requirement   Assisted
NotRequired      NotRequired  Allowed              Low                              Cellsite
```

Comment: Yep, meantime I found it. So cell, agps and gps is enabled, but wifi based not.